# C#: Can [Non-null object].ToString() be null?

Tags: c#, intellisense

I have the following piece of code:

```
string returnValue;
var registryValue = key.GetValue("something") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
returnValue = registryValue.ToString();
```

In the second line VS tells me `CS8600 - Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.`
I don't understand why it gives this warning. At this point `registryValue` is definetely `not null`, thus as far as I know `.ToString()` cannot return `null`.

Are there any `non null objects`, so that `object.ToString()` returns `null` or is this just a case of IntelliSense being unaware, that `null` cannot occure here? So can I safely use `returnValue = registryValue.ToString()!;` or do I have to handle possible `null` here?

Comment: Have a look at how `ToString` is declared: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0

Comment: Anyone can define their own type and override the `ToString` method so the answer is obviously yes, that method can return `null`. It would be odd to do so but that doesn't mean that there couldn't be a reason.